SwiftUI: Hide container when content is empty
Consider simplified example:
struct ContainerView<Content: View>: View {
    var header: String
    var content: Content

    init(header: String, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.header = header
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            Text(header)
            content
        }
    }
}

/// Usage
ContainerView(header: "Header") {
    if showFirst {
        Text("First").border(Color.yellow)
    }
    if showSecond {
        Text("Second").border(Color.green)
    }
}

I want entire container (including the header) to disappear when neither first nor second items are shown. In reality there can be many conditional items like this, with complicated conditions, which I really don't want to duplicate. Some checks can be wrapped into child view types.
Is there a way to check that content is effectively empty using SwiftUI APIs?

In iOS 18+, use Group(subviews:) to get an collection of all the subviews, and then you can just check if it is empty.
struct ContainerView<Content: View>: View {
    var header: String
    var content: Content

    init(header: String, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.header = header
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        Group(subviews: content) { subviews in
            if !subviews.isEmpty {
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    Text(header)
                    subviews
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Before iOS 18, you can use the _VariadicView API. The idea is the same,
var body: some View {
    _VariadicView.Tree(
        MultiViewRoot { subviews in
            if !subviews.isEmpty {
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    Text(header)
                    subviews
                }
            }
        }
    ) { content }
}

private struct MultiViewRoot<V: View>: _VariadicView_MultiViewRoot {
    @ViewBuilder let views: (_VariadicView.Children) -> V

    func body(children: _VariadicView.Children) -> some View {
        views(children)
    }
}

